# How to change the output database in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, linq

I'm pretty sure the way the question is phrased is incorrect, so sorry about that in advance. The problem is that an app I'm currently developing is supposed to connect to a specified MySQL database(which it does), read some data from it(which it also does) and then update/add data to it using WPF along the way. The problem is that the app is creating a second database file using the original mapping - essentialy making a copy of it - and writes to that database file instead, which is being put into the "\bin\Debug" directory of the project. So upon restarting the app, the unaltered data from the main database file is being read and the old changes are just overwritten next time the database file in the Debug directory is generated. So how do I make the app read AND write to the same database file? What's the general approach to make this work? I don't want to attach the whole project, so if you can tell me what part of the code to attach aswell that'd be great.

Comment: I am not sure what you try to achieve a database is no file that you copy so. you address different databases with database1,mytable and database2.mytable. try your code that you want to code, and when you encounter a problem show this

Comment: Your question is tagged `mysql` but MySQL doesn't support storing a database file in your application's `bin\Debug` directory. Are you using SQLite, perhaps? We can't answer the question without knowing exactly what database technology you're using.

Comment: What I am trying to do is connect to a database, read data from it and write data to it. Instead data is being read and then written to some kind of a copy database that's created on runtime inside '\bin\Debug\' directory.

Comment: The database was made using Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2019, I am connecting with it using LINQ. I have and .mdf file that's being read from and then instead of writing to it, the app is writing to a new database with the same mapping, name etc. but instead of the main fileit is being remade at runtime everytime inside the '\bin\Debug' as I've mentioned, essentialy creating a copy of my main input database file. The database is read from but never written to.